# How to consider special characters in ts_query and ts_vector as plain english

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How to include special characters `&, *, /` in `to_tsquery` and `to_tsvector` . It converts `boyce & doyl` as `{boyce:1 , doyl:1}`. How to treat them as char so they can be searched in a query ?

Comment: Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489617/how-do-you-do-phrase-based-full-text-search-in-postgres-that-takes-advantage-of) will answer your question.

Comment: You don't.  That is not what these features are for.  It is like asking how to store floats in an column declared as int.  Perhaps you want to use just text type, with the LIKE operator.